# How to run a function according the choice from the drop-list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have drop-down list with list of many options. Every time when a user make a choice then specific function starts.

```
$('#host').on('change', function() {

  if ( $('#host').val() == 'stack' ) stack();
  else if ( $('#host').val() == 'exchange' ) exchange();
  else if ( $('#host').val() == 'something' ) something();
  ...

}
```

The list become very long because more function will be added. Is there a shorter way to execute name of the function from `$('#host').val()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in different question, so the only way that works for me is:

```
eval($('#host').val() + "();");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call it from the `window's object`,

```
$('#host').on('change', function() {
  window[this.value]();
});
```

Comment: Ok, finally I found working solution. I needed to use `eval($('#host').val() + "();");`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this demo: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/CAKG4/)**

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function stack()
    {
        alert('Called function stack');
    }
    function exchange()
    {
        alert('Called function exchange');
    }
    function something()
    {
        alert('Called function something');
    }
    $('#host').on('change', function() {

      if ( $('#host').val() == 'stack' ) stack();
      else if ( $('#host').val() == 'exchange' ) exchange();
      else if ( $('#host').val() == 'something' ) something();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="host">
    <option value="">Select value</option>
    <option value="stack">stack</option>
    <option value="exchange">exchange</option>
    <option value="something">something</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question was different. And I found the answer. Thanks anyway.